# Why can $E^2=(m_0 c^2)^2+(pc)^2$ be extended for massless particles? You can't use $\lambda = h/p$

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

In these equations momentum $p$ is defined as either $\gamma m_0 v$ or $m v$. Every source I have seen says that when $m= 0$ then $E = pc$, but it doesn't give its reasoning as to why $p$ is then redefined as $p=E/c$. If the original definition is followed then $p = \infty * 0$ for massless particles. The matter wave equation was derived using $E=pc$, so it can't be used to explain $E=pc$.

Comment: Where is this definition?  I think it is a result not a definition.

Comment: You are using badly inconsistent, junk!, formulas. *Never* use "relativistic mass" again. There is only *one m*, the rest mass parameter (wich you called $m_0$, asking for trouble) and it is this mass that enters the expression for the energy. Wikipedia or a good text should help you.

Comment: Your title needs to have the $mc^2$ squared. It should read $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$.

Comment: I’ve never understood how you can have speed in the equation twice? With (mv times c) you have velocity times the speed of light? Seems like a fudge.

Comment: @BillAlsept It takes that form for units-consistency, given the historical definitions of the various quantities. One could use the "momentum-equivalent form" $(E/c)^2 = (mc)^2 + p^2$ instead of the "energy-equivalent form" above.

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards. It was the massless case of light that inspired De Broglie to extend these relations to the massive case.

Comment: True I just wanted it to be in the title so people wouldn't use it to answer why $E=pc$

Answer (score 0):

From the correct expression for the squared-energy,
$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2,$$
the magnitude of the relativistic momentum $p$
can be written in terms of the relativistic energy $E$ and the invariant mass $m$
by
$$p=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{E^2-(mc^2)^2}.$$
When $m=0$, the magnitude of the relativistic momentum $p$ takes the form
$$p\stackrel{m=0}{=}\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{E^2}=\frac{E}{c}.$$

(As @my2cts suggests, the de Broglie expression $\displaystyle \lambda_{dB}=\frac{h}{p}$ was historically developed after this energy expression was established.)

---

Note:
From a spacetime-geometric viewpoint, the energy expression
is obtained from the square-magnitude of the 4-momentum vector:
$$(mc)^2 =\tilde p \cdot \tilde p= \left(\frac{E}{c} \right)^2-\vec p\cdot \vec p.$$
The dimensionless spatial velocity $\displaystyle \frac{v}{c}$ associated with 4-momentum is
ratio of its spatial component to its temporal component:
$$\frac{v}{c}=\frac{pc}{E}.$$
Thus, $$v=\frac{pc}{E}c.$$

---

So, with $\displaystyle E=\frac{pc^2}{v}$,
we have
\begin{align}
p
&=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{E^2-(mc^2)^2}
\end{align}

- As above, when $m=0$, we have
  $$p \stackrel{m=0}{=}\frac{E}{c},$$
  which can also be characterized by
  $$p \stackrel{v=c}{=}\frac{E}{c}.$$
- When $m\neq 0$, substitute the expression for $E$
  \begin{align}
  p&=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{ \left( \frac{pc^2}{v} \right)^2-(mc^2)^2}\\
  \end{align}
  Solve this for $p$.... to find... **only when $\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2 \neq 1$** that
  $$p \stackrel{m\neq 0, \ v\neq c}{=}\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}.$$

Comment: But in the equation for massive particles $p=\gamma m_0 v$. So you are taking an equation used for massive particles and then applying it to massless particles, and using that to define momentum. How is that valid?

Comment: @user289980 I'm not taking $p=\gamma mv$ as a definition. The spacetime-definition for $p$ is as the "magnitude of the spatial component of the 4-momentum." In the nonzero invariant mass case, it will reduce to $p=\gamma mv$ (as a special case).

Comment: For a massive particle the 4-momentum is mass times 4-velocity. This is then used to form the mass-energy equivalence equation. Then the equation, which was used for massive particles, is then used to define the momentum of a massless particle as $E/c$. I got this from Wikipedia so I could be totally wrong though.

Comment: @user289980 I am not familiar with the history of ideas... But,  as JL Synge says "In this age of specialisation, history is best left to the historians". Look at my revised answer to show how, from a spacetime viewpoint, one can get $p=E/v$ which yields $p=E/c$ for massless particles and  $p=\gamma m v$ for a massive particles.

Comment: I meant $p=Ev/c^2$ (not $p=E/v$).

Answer (score 0):

In relativity energy and momentum are combined together to form a 4 vector, with the energy being the first component and momentum being the other 3. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum.

For a massive particle at rest we have $p = (m, 0, 0, 0)$, and for a particle moving at speed $v$ we have $p = (\gamma m, \gamma mv_x, \gamma mv_y, \gamma mv_z)$ = $(E, p_x, p_y, p_z)$. Note that the norm of this in Minkowski space is $E^2 - {p_x}^2 - {p_y}^2 - {p_z}^2 = E^2 - p^2$, which is invariant (for a massive particle it is the rest mass squared, $m^2$).

If we substitute $m = 0$ (for massless particles) the invariant expression becomes $E^2 - p^2 = 0$. The positive energy solution to this is $E=p$. All of this was done in units where $c=1$; for SI units it works out to $E=pc$.

Comment: When you substitute $m=0$ , why don't the masses in $E$ and $p$ go to zero as well? To me it seems like the mass gets hidden in those variables and then ignored.

Comment: There don't have to be "masses" in $E$ and $p$, they're just components of a vector (the four momentum). The rest mass is the length of the vector. Thanks to the hyperbolic structure of spacetime, this may be $0$ even if the components are non-zero. The Wikipedia article has more details.